# Adding PHP includes to my Warp JoomlaTemplate

Tags: php, joomla

I recently purchased this script from Code Canyon and I want to work it in to my Warp Joomla template.

http://www.geertdedeckere.be/shop/thumbsup/help#template-list

I hope someone on here has some experience with the Warp framework. I have followed the creator's instructions to the T but I keep getting a white screen. Each Warp template is based on a config.php and template.config.php file. I have tried adding code as outlined on YooTheme support ticket: http://www.yootheme.com/support/question/28978 with no avail.

I also tried doing some other experiments, but while I wait on YooTheme's ridiculously long support response, has anyone the slightest idea of how I can call the initial PHP function and the CSS/Javascript files in my Warp template? I managed ot get as far as the CSS (I am unsure whether or not the init.php call is being seen, even with a relative path. The creator's original commands:

```
<?php echo ThumbsUp::css() ?>  
    <?php echo ThumbsUp::javascript() ?>
```

Are giving me a white screen, which I assume (and I don't know PHP inside and out / but I am tech literate) is because either the original call is not being placed before all other content output, due to a joomla structural issue I am not aware of (i.e. I am putting the code in the wrong place), or I am incorrectly placing the echo commands. Please help!

Comment: A "white screen of death" in PHP generally indicates a function has failed miserable, but PHP display errors are turned off. What error reporting do you have turned on?

Comment: Would need to see some code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned a Joomla! version so I'm presumming 2.5.x in my comments.

*Putting this type of functionality in a Joomla! template is not a good idea, you would be better off looking at one of the existing [extensions for Joomla! that provide "Ratings and Review" functionality](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/ratings-a-reviews/) including simply like/dislike options. The majority are free.*

Having said that to determine the root cause of a PHP problem you will need to do the following:

1. Turn on "Debug System" (`Site->Global Configuration->System->Debug Settigns`)
2. Turn the sites "Error Reporting" level up,(`Site->Global Configuration->Server->Server Settings`). If it's currently `None` the start with `Simple` and work your way up (unless you're completely confident that you can log in modify the `configuration.php` file manually if the site stops working after ramping the error reporting all the way up.

**N.B.** Do not leave these settings on for any longer than necessary.

From the output generated you should be able to pin point the error, or the area the problem is occurring in. At that point you could extend your original question and provide us with more details like the error message, the code that causing it etc...